# SASL XMPP authentication fails with <not - authorized>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xmpp, monodevelop, openfire

I am beginner in Unity and first time implementing XMPP in Unity, but not able to establish connection with server. 
Below is error logs :

```
 <stream:stream to='192.168.1.225' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>

 <stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" from="daydate" xml:lang="en" id="80mu0xgew1" version="1.0" >

 <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls" /><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth" /><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register" /></stream:features>

 <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls" />

 <proceed xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls" />

 <stream:stream to='192.168.1.225' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0' xml:lang='en'>

 <stream:stream xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" from="daydate" xml:lang="en" id="80mu0xgew1" version="1.0" >

 <stream:features xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"><mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><mechanism>PLAIN</mechanism><mechanism>ANONYMOUS</mechanism><mechanism>SCRAM-SHA-1</mechanism><mechanism>CRAM-MD5</mechanism><mechanism>DIGEST-MD5</mechanism></mechanisms><compression xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/compress"><method>zlib</method></compression><auth xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-auth" /><register xmlns="http://jabber.org/features/iq-register" /></stream:features>

 <auth xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" mechanism="DIGEST-MD5" />

 <challenge xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">cmVhbG09ImRheWRhdGUiLG5vbmNlPSJ0anpIMkhxMGJnRC9hVVdmNHAvZTNGaWdFYVpod0pHRGdzdkkrYXBPIixxb3A9ImF1dGgiLGNoYXJzZXQ9dXRmLTgsYWxnb3JpdGhtPW1kNS1zZXNz</challenge>

 <response xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">dXNlcm5hbWU9InNhZ2FyIixyZWFsbT0iZGF5ZGF0ZSIsbm9uY2U9InRqekgySHEwYmdEL2FVV2Y0cC9lM0ZpZ0VhWmh3SkdEZ3N2SSthcE8iLGNub25jZT0iZjdmZmY5YjBmZDEwZGQ4ZGMxYWVhMzg2MDM2OTJmMzNkNDdjNGFlZWNhMTcwNzYwYzlhNmZlZjQwZjAyMmZmMCIsbmM9MDAwMDAwMDEscW9wPWF1dGgsZGlnZXN0LXVyaT0ieG1wcC8xOTIuMTY4LjEuMjI1IixjaGFyc2V0PXV0Zi04LHJlc3BvbnNlPTJkYWMyMDMxMDA2NDIxM2E3ZDBlOTFkMDUzYzQ1NjYx</response>

 <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized /></failure>

 <failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl"><not-authorized /></failure>

 </stream:stream>
```

Below is code to establish connection with server:

```
void Start () {


    connection = new JUN.Connection();

    connection.Server = "192.168.1.225"; 
    connection.Port = 5222;
    connection.Username = "username";  //Without @domainName
    connection.Password = "password";

    connection.AutoRoster = true;
    connection.AutoAgents = false;
    connection.AutoPresence = true;
    connection.AutoResolveConnectServer = false;

    connection.SocketConnectionType = SocketConnectionType.Direct;

    connection.OnReadXml += new XmlHandler(OnReadXml);
    connection.OnWriteXml += new XmlHandler(OnWriteXml);
    connection.OnLogin += delegate (object sender) { queue.Enqueue(() => OnLogin(sender)); };
    connection.OnClose += delegate (object sender) { queue.Enqueue(() => OnClose(sender)); };
    connection.OnError += new ErrorHandler(OnError);
    connection.OnPresence += delegate (object sender, Presence pres) { queue.Enqueue(() => OnPresence(sender, pres)); };
    connection.OnMessage += delegate (object sender, Message msg) { queue.Enqueue(() => OnMessage(sender, msg)); };
    connection.OnAuthError += new XMPPElementHandler(OnAuthError);
    connection.OnSocketError += new ErrorHandler(OnSocketError);
    connection.OnStreamError += new XMPPElementHandler(OnStreamError);

    connection.OnConnectionStateChanged += delegate (object sender, ConnectionState state) { queue.Enqueue(() => OnConnectionStateChanged(sender, state)); };
    connection.Open ();

}
```

I am facing this issue and go through many docs with same issue, but not getting any solution.
I am using Openfire server.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your XMPP domain is daydate, not the ip you set in the server property. 
Set server to daydate and connectserver to you ip.

Would be easier when you setup the proper dns and SRV records for your server.
The XMPP domain is part of the SASL authentication, additional to username and password.

Comment: Then add your new logs please, and verify that username and password is correct.

Comment: Code working fine with live server but not working with local server created in my machine.

Comment: "daydate" have to be the name of the "live" server but your local server has another one, just check it on openfire admin panel